mysql in docker. Can't create thread to handle bootstrap
I have the following simple project
.
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
└── init.sql

where the Dockerfile is
FROM mysql:8.0-debian
RUN apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y locales \
   && sed -i -E 's/# (ja_JP.UTF-8)/\1/' /etc/locale.gen \
   && locale-gen \
   && update-locale LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 \
   && apt-get clean \
   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV LC_ALL ja_JP.UTF-8

the docker compose yml is
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    build: .
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

and the init.sql is
-- Create a table named "vehicles" with three columns
CREATE TABLE vehicles (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

-- Insert sample data into the "vehicles" table
INSERT INTO vehicles (name, type) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Car');
INSERT INTO vehicles (name, type) VALUES ('Honda', 'Motorcycle');
INSERT INTO vehicles (name, type) VALUES ('Isuzu', 'Truck');

I have managed to build it (previously at home, this also did not work). The problem is that I can not make docker compose up
My first attempt failed like:
docker compose up 
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container data-base-mysql-1  Recreated                                                                                                                 0.1s
Attaching to data-base-mysql-1
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17 02:23:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1debian12 started.
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17 02:23:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17 02:23:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1debian12 started.
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17 02:23:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17T02:23:27.639395Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.39) initializing of server in progress as process 80
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17T02:23:27.640863Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17T02:23:27.640869Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17T02:23:27.640910Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17T02:23:27.641063Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.39)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
data-base-mysql-1 exited with code 1

What files? I did not mount any files?
So I did docker volume ls which gave me a bunch of data I did not identify but anyway I did docker volume prune
With that I tried again and this time I have a different type of error
Attaching to data-base-mysql-1
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17 02:26:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1debian12 started.
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17 02:26:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17 02:26:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1debian12 started.
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17 02:26:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17T02:26:36.671156Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.39) initializing of server in progress as process 80
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17T02:26:36.690674Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010001] [Server] Can't create thread to handle bootstrap (errno: 1)
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17T02:26:36.690710Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17T02:26:36.690720Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17T02:26:36.690729Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
data-base-mysql-1  | 2024-09-17T02:26:36.691230Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.39)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
data-base-mysql-1 exited with code 1

I tried to add this to the yaml file
command: >
      bash -c "chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql && /entrypoint.sh mysqld"

but the error persists.
I am very confused now.

Why docker said that /var/lib/mysql/ had files? what files?
Why docker can't create a thread to handle bootstrap
What can I do to make this work?


Are you running docker compose build or docker compose up --build? Only thing I can think of is you created an earlier image that has files in /var/lib/mysql for some reason

@Phil I eliminated any unrelated image (except the one I am creating) and it gave me the first error ("data directory has files in it"). I eliminated that one too, and now it gives me the second error again ("cant create thread")

Do you get the same problem if you skip the image build and just use mysql:8.0-debian in your compose file? It won't have your locale customisation but at least it could help narrow down the problem. Another thing to check would be running the image and getting a shell then inspect the /var/lib/mysql directory

@Phil Unfortunately it is weekend so I cannot try it in the same environment, but I tried it in one in which even worse, I could not even build the docker compose. So I did as you proposed and I could actually do the docker compose up (with a lot of weird messages about "stopping temporary servers" but in the end I could run and see the database.

@Phil Next I will try it in the original environment to see if it works there too. I wonder what the problem is with the threads and the locale
